# ngrx: Normalization structures vs Observable entities

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm trying to figure out how to handle with "entity arrays" into my ngrx Store.

I mean, guess that I've a collection of `PlanDTO` I'm getting from my api server. So, according to several documentation I've read, I need to create some kind of "table" in order to store them:

```
export interface IPlan {
    id?: string;
    name?: string;
    ...
}

export interface IPlanRedux {
    byId: { [key: string]: IPlan };
    allIds: Array<string>;
}
```

So, when a `'LOAD_PLANS'` action is dispatched an effect is lauched as well:

```
@Injectable()
export class PlanEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private store$: Store<IStore>,
    private planService: PlansService,
  ) { }

  @Effect({ dispatch: true })
  loadPlans$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType('LOAD_PLANS')
    .switchMap((action: Action) =>
      this.planService.list()
        .map((plans: Array<PlanDTO>) => {
          return { type: 'LOAD_PLANS_SUCCESS', payload: plans };
        })
        .catch((err: ApiError) => {
          return Observable.of({ type: 'LOAD_PLANS_FAILED', payload: { code: err.code, msg: err.message } });
        })
    );
}
```

As you can see if everything hass been fine, another action is "dispatched": `'LOAD_PLANS_SUCCESS'`. So the reducer for this action is:

```
private static loadPlansSuccess(plansRdx: IPlanRedux, type, payload: Array<PlanDTO>) {
    const plans = payload;
    const newPlans = plans.filter(plan => !plansRdx.byId[plan.id]);

    const newPlanIds = newPlans.map(plan => plan.id);
    const newPlanEntities = plans.reduce((entities: { [id: string]: IPlan }, plan: IPlan) => {
        return Object.assign(entities, {
            [plan.id]: plan
        });
    },
    {});

    return {
        ids: [ ...plansRdx.allIds, ...newPlanIds ],
        byId: Object.assign({}, plansRdx.byId, newPlanEntities),
    };
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, nevertheless, I don't quite figure out. I think that there are 2 concepts here I need to understand.

1. Internal table in order to store redux structure.
2. Front-end components.

The main headache I've is I need to handle with an `Observable<IPlanRedux>` instead of an `Observable<IPlan>` into my components. I mean, into my components I want to treat with `IPlan`s instead of tables with fields `allIds` or `ById`.

So, internally, I'm taking care of my `IPlanRedux` table, but by other side, I'd like to "emit" which plans have been removed and which ones added.

I don't know id I've explained so well.

**EDIT**

I've tried to use selectors:

```
export interface IPlanRedux {
    entities: { [key: string]: IPlan };
    ids: Array<string>;
}

export const getPlans = (planRdx: IPlanRedux) => planRdx.entities;

const getPlansState = (state: IStore) => state.plans;
export const getPlanEntities = createSelector(getPlansState, getPlans);
```

Into my component:

```
this.plans$ = this.store$.select(fromRoot.getPlanEntities)
    .map(plan => {
    if (plan.id != null)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: "Rules&Concepts" are just guides that should help you to find a good solution for your application - I don't know anyone that implements all those rules to an absolute 100%.
Every application is somewhat individual and there is no "one fits all"-solution.

So, just because someone tells you to use a table-like-structure, doesn't mean that this is the best solution for your issue (on the other hand it also doesn't mean that it will be a bad solution) - since you are the only one here knowing your data and your requirements you are probably the only person able to make that judgement - so don't blindely trust in some rules and expect that there won't be any downsides.

---

As for your questions:

**1. Internal table in order to store redux structure.**

A redux- or ngrx-store is typically used in combination with immutable objects (which makes change-detection performing a lot better) - In this case it is a lot easier to manage your data in a flat structure instead of a nested structure, because in a flat(table) structure your only have to re-create 2 levels of your data at most. However, when you have deeply nested Objects, you have to re-create more layers of data (depending on your nesting-depth) when performing a data-mutation.

So: When you are not working with immutables you won't really benefit from one or the other data-structure. (I'm not making any recommendation here, this is a technical decision, which is up to you, personally I like working with immutables, but I did not start with that)

**2. Front-end components**

Here, again, there are some "rules" like "smart&dumb components", "select-statements vs. let-functions" ect. - again: there is not really the perfect, all-mighty solution.

As for the `Observable<IPlanRedux>` - you don't *have* to do that everywhere - if you don't get along with [let-functions](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/blob/master/src/app/reducers/index.ts#L113) you could create some service-class and implement some simple select-statement there:

```
class StoreService {
    iPlans$ = this.store.select(state => state.planRedux)
        .map(planRedux => planRedux.allIds.map(id => planRedux.byId[id]));
}
```

---

Some **personal** advice, depending on your case:

**If you are doing this project as a hobby & for learing:** Go nuts, try out as much as you can and learn as much as you can, break as much as you can. - You **will** have setbacks, you **will** need to make refactorings as you learn, but it will be worth it. NGRX and the redux pattern in general is a **really** nice tool, but very tricky to wrap your head around, especially if you are used to other patterns.

**If you are doing this project for a client and as a production-ready application:** Stick to the stuff you already know or accept the fact, that there **will** be inevitable consequences in quality&time, if this is your first ngrx and/or angular2-project (unless you are some mad genius ;-) ).

Comment: Awesome @osln. I tried to use selectors. I've tried to give a description about the problem I've right now. Could you provide my some lights?

Comment: Well, you are selecting your `planEntities`, which is of type: `{ [key: string]: IPlan }` - so I guess it is correct, that there is no id-attribute on your entities-object, the id will only be available on `plan["some-plan-id"].id`

Comment: I've created a new post on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766012/ngrx-selectors-structure-mapping). I hope I've explained a bit better.